# Connect to Database at different location through Entity Framework (MVC || ORACLE DB)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have 15 units of our organisation at different location, and all units have same table structure and coding, but the database is locally installed on those units.

Now I am creating a web application, which will be deployed on our corporate server, and I have to make connectivity through MPLS.

Now  I am stuck at a problem, All databases have different schema name, on login screen i have username, password, and unit name fields, Based on unit name, I make connectivity to the specific unit database. Till now, everything was working fine as I tested on different location db having same schema name, but couple days back I connected unit having different schema name and it throw error, as Table or View Does not exist.
If I use traditional approach, Eg. Using OracleConnection, OracleCommand etc. it is possible, but in Entity Framework I didn't find any solution.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

In EF6 you can have multiple contexts, just specify the name for the default database schema in the  OnModelCreating method of you DbContext derived class (where the Fluent-API configuration is). This will work in EF6:

```
public partial class CustomerModel : DbContext
{   
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Customer");

        // Fluent API configuration
    }   
}
```

This example will use "Customer" as prefix for your database tables (instead of "dbo"). More importantly it will also prefix the __MigrationHistory table(s), e.g. Customer.__MigrationHistory. So you can have more than one __MigrationHistory table in a single database, one for each context. So the changes you make for one context will not mess with the other.

Comment: protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var _dal = new DBConnect();
var schemaName = _dal.getSchemaName();
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schemaName);
        }

It is not working, I debugged it, this method is not triggering

Comment: i am using following code every time I create instance of context
 public string Connect(string Company_Code)
 {
 string connString = SetConnectionString(Company_Code);
 EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityString = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder()
 {
                Provider = "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client",
                Metadata = "res://*/Models.ERPModel.csdl|res://*/Models.ERPModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.ERPModel.msl",
                ProviderConnectionString = connString.ToString()
            };
            return entityString.ConnectionString;
        }

Comment: You can refer this link for seeing default schema info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-schema.   I would suggest you create two context classes. One with default schema and one with the new schema and choose your context class based on Schema type.